# Remove texture in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, texture

I'd like to remove the texture from a logo I made.

I'm not sure how to attach the AI file, but here is a screenshot of what the logo looks like.

[image]

I've tried going into the Appearance panel, but there didn't seem to be anything texture- related there.

[image]

I also tried using the Live Paint Bucket (K) tool to just fill "over" the texture, but that didn't get rid of the texture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Double-click** the word "Contents" in the **Appearance Panel**.

Keep double-clicking "Contents" until you see the texture effect. Then remove it.